# Casting pointer types on different architectures

Tags: c, pointers, casting, endianness

I have the following structure and "getter" function that returns `a` cast to an unsigned integer:

```
struct s {
    uint32_t a;
};

void get_a(struct s *st, unsigned *ret)
{
    *ret = (unsigned)st->a;
}
```

The following code is run:

```
struct s st;
uint16_t x;

st.a = 1;
get_a(&st, (unsigned *)&x);
```

And for x86_64, i686, armv7hl, ppc64le and other architectures `x == 1`, but for ppc64 `x == 0`. Why is this? Little- vs. big-endian?

Comment: Set a to 0x12345678. Little-endian machines will return 0x5678, big-endian 0x1234. To maintain same behavior on all machines use htonl/htons/ntohl/ntohs functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have:

```
uint16_t x;
```

but then you try to write to that memory location as if it were the location of `unsigned`.

If you were on a system where `unsigned` and `uint16_t` are the same type, this is fine. But on other systems, such as the one you used for your code sample, you are in trouble.

First of all, this causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) by violating the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). Variables of type `uint16_t` may only be written to through lvalues of type `uint16_t`, or a character type.

But even if it did not violate strict aliasing, you would still cause UB by writing outside the bounds of `x`. Probably, you are writing 4 or 8 bytes into a 2-byte memory location, so it will overflow the buffer.

There could also be UB if `x` is not correctly [aligned](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/) for `unsigned`.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that endianness has nothing to do in this case.

Comment: @black it sort of does: *if* all of the UB in the code doesn't produce nasal demons this time, we might expect that the `1` bit being written appears either inside `x` or outside `x` depending on the system endianness

Comment: Lesson learned: Do not cast pointers, or at least be very careful with what you are doing. There mostly ever is a different solution. Here a temporary `unsigned` typed variable would have wiped away all uncertainties.